# Jboss eap 7 configuration

Tags: java, jboss, jboss7.x

I have downloaded the Jboss eap 7 to my system. I want to deploy my war/ ear file or configure my application source in the server. Can anyone help me with the steps for doing the same

Answer (score 0):

You can deploy your ear/war using the JBoss Command Line Interface (CLI):

```
$JBOSS_HOME/bin/jboss-cli.sh --connect --controller=127.0.0.1:9999 --user=manager --password=password deploy path/to/your.ear
```

This can be scripted if required. Undeploying is the same:

```
$JBOSS_HOME/bin/jboss-cli.sh --connect --controller=127.0.0.1:9999 --user=manager --password=password undeploy your.ear
```

Answer (score 0):

```
To stop, start, restart & status check the JBOSS service, use following commands :
•   systemctl stop jboss-eap-rhel.service
•   systemctl start jboss-eap-rhel.service
•   systemctl restart jboss-eap-rhel.service
•   systemctl status jboss-eap-rhel.service


To add management console user, use following steps :

•   cd /data/jboss-eap-7.0/binlssh ./add-user.sh
•   what type of user do you wish to add?
a.  Management User (mgmt-users.properties)
b.  Application User (application-users.properties)
•   Enter a and go to next (i.e. (a) :a)
•   Enter the details of the new user to add.
Using realm ‘ManagementRealm’ as discovered from the existing property files.
Username : xyz
•   If user already exists, it shows update option otherwise it shows create option.
•   User ‘xyz’ already exists and is enabled, would you like to…
a.  Update the existing user password and roles
b.  Disable the existing user
c.  Type a new username
•   Enter a and go to next (i.e. (a) :a)
•   Password : ******
•   What groups do you want this user to belong to? (Please enter a comma separated list, or leave blank for none) [ManagementRealm] : 
•   Just leave as blank and enter
•   Is this new user going to be used for one AS process to connect to another AS process?
e.g. for a slave host controller connecting to the master or for a remoting connection for server to server EJB calls.
yes/no? yes


To add environment variable, use following steps :

•   Go to following path i.e. ../jboss-eap-7.0/bin/ and open the file standalone.conf and add Denvironment=prod

Example:

# Specify options to pass to the Java VM.
#
if [ "x$JAVA_OPTS" = "x" ]; then
   JAVA_OPTS="-Xms1303m -Xmx1303m -XX:MetaspaceSize=96M -XX:MaxMetaspaceSize=256m -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true"
   JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS -Djboss.modules.system.pkgs=$JBOSS_MODULES_SYSTEM_PKGS -Djava.awt.headless=true -Denvironment=prod"
else
   echo "JAVA_OPTS already set in environment; overriding default settings with values: $JAVA_OPTS"


If JBOSS 8080 and 9990 ports are unable to access from remote, use following steps :

    Go to following path i.e. ../jboss-eap-7.0/standalone/configuration and open the file standalone.xml and point actual IP address as mentioned in example.

Example :

<interfaces>
        <interface name="management">
            <inet-address value="${jboss.bind.address.management:172.16.26.68}"/>
        </interface>
        <interface name="public">
            <inet-address value="${jboss.bind.address:172.16.26.68}"/>
        </interface>
</interfaces>
```

Comment: It seems you copied your answer from some source. Please read [How to reference material written by others](https://stackoverflow.com/help/referencing).

Comment: Based on my self experience only wrote. not copied

Comment: OK then, but it seems like it's copied because of bad formatting. The answer should be edited.

Answer (score 0):

After configured above mentioned steps, hit this URL http://localhost:9990/console/App.html and then it shows authentication prompt window for management username and password. After that tap start link in Deployments tab. Choose the war file and deploy.